# How to map multiple table types to a single table without multiple FK references

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entities

I am currently trying to map multiple different tables to a single table, like this:

```
Person

| id | first_name | last_name |
| -- | ---------- | --------- |
| 1  | John       | Doe       |

Place

| id | place_name  |
| -- | ----------  |
| 1  | White House |

Address

| id | ...typical address columns... | related_id | related_type |
| -- | ----------------------------- | ---------- | ------------ |
| 1  | address stuff                 | 1          | Person       |
| 2  | more address stuff            | 1          | Place        |
```

I know how to represent this in the database obviously, so that's not the issue here. My issue is how do I represent the relationship in my Entity classes, as the typical `@JoinColumn` annotation approach doesn't seem like it will work since we need both the `related_id` and `related_type` columns

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    ??? what to do here ???
    private List<Address> addresses;

    // omitted getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Place {

    private String placeName;

    @OneToOne
    ??? what to do here ???
    private Address address;

    // omitted getters and setters
}
```

Is there any way to do this with JPA / Hibernate? I've found similar questions here but they are from ages ago and none of the solutions were really appropriate as they had more to do with inheritance.

Comment: Think of it the other way - what are you going to put into an Address java class to make what you want 'work'? Those other answers likely have Place and Person extend something so that the Address->RootType mapping can be defined to determine the id/Type columns (in EclipseLink, this is a VariableOneToOne https://eclipse.dev/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_variableonetoone.htm ). Otherwise, you'd have to define your own filter on the Person->Address so that it includes something to use the related_type column- but you'd have similar issues when writing that relationship

Comment: Wouldn't it makes more sense if a Person reference many places and a place had one Address? And this model doesn't work if you have multiple people at the same address anyway.

Comment: @Chris I'm using Person/Place/Address as an example of the type of relationship I need to model. In my case the entities representing Person and Place are not related, so there wouldn't be a way to create the kind of 1-to-m mapping you suggest. Obviously Person m-to-m Address would work with a third join table, which is not ideal but may be necessary in my case to be able to handle the relationship I'm trying to model.